# how to conditionally add resources to a call

Tags: scala, gatling

I know that while chaining off of a `exec()` I have the super handy method `doIf()` which is great. However within the `HttpRequestBuilder` there is no such option. For our testing need, we will for some runs want only our calls, while in others we will also want to request resources with the calls. In the basic scenario below how would I situationally add resources

```
    http("post login")
      .post("/somesite")
      .headers(someheaders)
      .formParam("user", "Bob")
      .formParam("password", "notpassword")
      .resources(
       http("get javascript prototype")
         .get("/firstResource"),
       http("get javascript scriptaculous")
         .get("/secondResource"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the resources you want to get are a known list, then the easiest way would be to model two separate login requests, one with the resources request and one without. Then use something like doIf (as you suggested) to decide which to invoke.